# Hashicorp consul FQDN

Tags: vmware, consul, vcloud-director-rest-api, hashicorp

1. I have a cluster of VM (vmWare vCloude) with consul server installed on one of them.
2. communication between VM is done **ONLY** view internal network IP. using ExternalIP is blocked. so consul agents installed on other VM are getting the internal IP as **advertised  address**.
3. I created a few Microservices using k8s that is installed on VM outside the cluster. I can communicate with the cluster ONLY with the ExternalIP.

problem:
consul is returning an **advertised address** from the VM and it can only be either, internal or external IP. if I choose the internalIP then I cannot use it from outside the cluster and if I use the externalIP, then all agents installed within the cluster will not be able to communicate. I did not find a why of configuring the advertised address with FQDN.

Did anyone faced this issue or have a solution for it?
Thank you,
Lior

Comment: Are the microservices running on Kubernetes trying to reach the Consul API, or are they running Consul agents that are attempting to join the existing cluster?

Comment: They are running consul agents.

Comment: If the Consul agents are part of the same datacenter, they will need to have direct IP reachability to all other agents. If the agents are in different Consul datacenter, you can use the [`advertise_wan`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_advertise-wan) parameter on the VM-based hosts to specify an alternate address to connect to. Unfortunately this is only half of the solution. The same would need to be configured on the Kubernetes hosts, but that is not currently supported by the Helm chart. If you need this feature, I recommend filing a feature request in the Consul-k8s repo.